# Tails 2.3 will not install on Windows 10

Tags: tails

Downloaded Tails 2.2.1 a few weeks ago but just got around to installing on 9 May. Installed perfectly but got warning new version was available.(2.3)

Downloaded 2.3 and made intermediary Tails which pc would not boot up from (unlike 2.2.1). Downloaded several times, used 2 different computers, reformatted usb drive several times, but 2.3. will not boot up.

Has anyone else had this problem and is there a fix?

Comment: and what the relation to Windows 10?

Comment: Could you explain step-by-step what you did and what exactly went wrong?